# Rspec tests hang with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

I am (very) new to Ruby and can't figure out why my rspec hangs. I have two regular expressions in the method given below. If I comment out either, rspec works. But if both are present, rspec hangs ([link to full project, including tests](https://github.com/JenHomann/ruby-katas/tree/master/day2), if it helps provide context)

**Sample** input:

```
pairings= [["Joe Johnson", "Jane Johnson"], ["Sarah Smith", "Bob Jones"]]
```

**Desired** output:

```
self.valid_pairs?(pairings) => false ... because the last names in the pairings[0] are the same
```

**Code**:

```
def self.valid_pairs?(pairings)

 validated_pairings = []
 pairings.each do |p|
   match1 = /(\w*)\s(\w*)|(\w*)\s(\w*)\s(\w*)/.match(p[0]).to_a 
   match2 = /(\w*)\s(\w*)|(\w*)\s(\w*)\s(\w*)/.match(p[1]).to_a

   if match1.last != match2.last
     validated_pairings << p
   else
   end
 end

 if validated_pairings == pairings
   true
 else
   false
 end

end
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't have too much sense since that can match only a whitespace. Can you put a sample data and your desired output?

Comment: I added sample input and desired output. I'm not sure if this helps - this is my 1st posted question so please tell me if I'm misunderstanding your request.

Comment: I see, what you want to do is to compare last names. The regex you need is to grab the lastname though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to grab the lastnames:

```
(\w+)$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/kM2fU1/1)**

[image]

To get the content from capturing group you can do:

```
lastname = /(\w+)$/.match(p[0]).captures
```

So, for:

```
lastname = /(\w+)$/.match("Sarah Smith").captures
// lastname => "Smith"
```

I leave coding to you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex to fetch the last word you can use [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split):

```
match1 = p[0].split
match2 = p[1].split
```

You could also simplify your code a lot by using [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
def self.valid_pairs?(pairings)
  pairings.all? do |p1, p2|
    p1.split.last != p2.split.last
  end
end
```

The above code returns true only if all the elements in the `pairings` array return true for not having the same last name for both names.

Answer (score 0):

It would be less confusing if your method were:

```
def any_matching_last_names?(pairings)
  pairings.any? { |p1,p2| p1.last_name == p2.last_name }
end
```

where `last_name` extracts the last names from `p1` and `p2` by whatever means you like (e.g, `p.split.last` or `p[/\w+$/]`. `pairings` would be "valid" if this method returned `false`, so you might use it like this:

```
list.add(pairings) unless any_matching_last_names?(pairings)
```